# Can a delegate take a generic as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I've created a class that works with my cache to get cached items. If the items are not cached then it calls a function to get the actual value.

This class has eight methods, all with almost identical code except for the function they call. I've created a function called GetObject which takes a delegate to call if it can't find an item in the class.

I can't get my code to compile because of the following error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`' to
>   '`MyFunction<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>`'.

**Am I doing something wrong or am I'm trying to do something that can't be done?**

Here's the code I'm trying.

```
public delegate T MyFunction<T>(string s); 

public T GetCultures<T>(string s) where T : class {
    return NewListOfStrings(s) as T;
}


public List<string> NewListOfStrings(string s) {
    return new List<string> { s };
}


public List<string> GetListOfStrings(string sitename) {
    string key = cachingService.CreateValidKey("stringvalue");

     //This is the line that fails to compile
     var foundItems = GetObject<List<string>>(key, 
                                      GetCultures<List<string>>(sitename));

     return foundItems;
}



public T GetObject<T>(string key, MyFunction<T> f) where T : class {

    T foundItems = (T)cachingService.GetCachedItem(key);

    if (foundItems == null) {
        lock (key) {
            foundItems = (T)cachingService.GetCachedItem(key);

            if (foundItems == null) {
                foundItems = f as T;

                if (foundItems != null) {
                     cachingService.SetCachedItem(key, foundItems, 5, 
                                                        Constants.MINUTES);
                }
            }
         }
     }

     return foundItems;
 }
```

**Solution**

```
public T GetObject<T>(string key, Func<T> getFromRepository) where T : class {

    T foundItems = (T)cachingService.GetCachedItem(key);

    if (foundItems == null) {
        lock (key) {
           foundItems = (T)cachingService.GetCachedItem(key);

           if (foundItems == null) {
               foundItems = getFromRepository() as T;

               if (foundItems != null) {
                   cachingService.SetCachedItem(key, foundItems, 5, 
                                                      Constants.MINUTES);
               }
            }
        }
    }

    return foundItems;
}


public AreaModels.Site GetSiteByName(string sitename) {
   string key = cachingService.CreateValidKey(
                                 string.Format("Site_{0}", sitename));

   return GetObject<AreaModels.Site>(key, 
                                 () => efRepository.GetSiteByName(sitename));
}


public List<AreaModels.Culture> GetCulturesForSite(string sitename) {
   string key = cachingService.CreateValidKey(
                                  string.Format("Cultures_{0}", sitename));

   return GetObject<List<AreaModels.Culture>>(key, 
                       () => efRepository.GetCulturesForSite(sitename));
}


public List<AreaModels.Resource> Resources(string sitename, int appId) {
   string key = cachingService.CreateValidKey(
                                 string.Format("ResourcesFor{0}", sitename));

   return GetObject<List<AreaModels.Resource>>(key, 
               () => efRepository.GetResourcesBySiteAndAppId(sitename, appId));
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong: you are passing a list of strings to a method that expects a MyFunction<List<string>>.  You're doing other things wrong, too, such as `foundItems = f as T;`.  This should be `foundItems = f(someString);` or `foundItems = f.Invoke(someString);`

Comment: I don't believe you can pass in a parameter that declares a generic type - it must be concrete at that point. Here ... `public T GetObject<T>(string key, MyFunction<T> f) where T : class`

Comment: @Daniel To phoogs comment, your line is calling the `GetCultures` method, which means the result is given to `GetObject`, you simply need to supply `GetCultures` as a method group, but it means that `sitename` will need to be passed in separately too: `GetObject<List<string>>(key, GetCultures<List<string>>); // sitename needs to be in here somewhere.`

Comment: possibly better use `T GetObject<T>(string key, T f)`, any way you use this parameter `f` as value, not as function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the result of the function rather than the function itself. You can use a lambda like so:

```
var foundItems = GetObject<List<string>>(key, 
                                  name => GetCultures<List<string>>(sitename));
```

You also have this line:

```
foundItems = f as T;
```

Here you're trying to cast the function itself to its return type, which won't work. Instead you could do:

```
foundItems = f(name);
```

But now your problem is that you'd have to pass the name into `GetObject`, because otherwise it won't be accessible where it's needed. The reason for this is there's a mismatch between `MyFunction`, which takes a `string`, and what you actually want, which is a function that can be evaluated within `GetObject` without needing the name parameter to be passed in.

So what you should really do is change your delegate to:

```
public delegate T MyFunction<T>();
```

Or alternatively get rid of the delegate altogether and have the `f` parameter be a `Func<T>`.

With either of these options, you can pass in the lamba with no parameter required:

```
var foundItems = GetObject<List<string>>(key, 
                                  () => GetCultures<List<string>>(sitename));
```

And evaluate it like:

```
foundItems = f();
```

Note that it's a bit roundabout to create a lambda to pass it into another method just to then evaluate it, rather than just passing the result in directly. So unless there's some reason that you need to do this in some cases, you might instead want to change the `f` parameter to take a type `T` instead. In this case I suspect you're doing it to lazily evaluate the function so that you don't have to evaluate if the result is already cached. That would probably be a valid reason, assuming you're not optimizing for performance prematurely.

Comment: This will compile, but notice that in the body he'll try to cast `x => GetCultures<List<string>>(sitename)` to `List<string>`, which won't work.

Comment: Right, he'd need to replace `foundItems = f as T` with `foundItems = f() as T;` if that's what he wanted

Comment: And the ```as T``` part is unnecessary since the ```Function<T>``` (I guess) returns a ```T``` anyway.

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for your response and edits. It's all much appreciated. I wouldn't be passing the 'key' parameter to the function. I use the key to look in the cache. If nothing is there then I call the function, and the parameters the function takes are defined in the line set up with GetListOfStrings.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake In that case you could do a lambda like `() => GetCultures<List<string>>(sitename))`, if you changed `MyFunction` not to take any parameters. Alternatively you could do something like `name => GetCultures<List<string>>(name))`, then have the name as an extra parameter to `GetObject`.

Comment: @DanielHollinrake Basically if you want to pass a function that takes a string parameter to `GetObject` then evaluate it within `GetObject`, you need to make sure the string you want to pass in can be accessed from within `GetObject`.

Comment: @BenAaronson Hi Ben, Thank you for your comments. I tried running my code and found that it didn't call the function I passed in. Your last comment is pointing me in the right direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've marked this as my accepted answer since it helped me achieve what I needed to do. I'll post an update to my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't creating a delegate. You are actually evaluating the method before calling `GetObject`. Easily fixed:

```
    var foundItems = GetObject<List<string>>(key,
        name => GetCultures<List<string>>(name));
```

Note also that it isn't obvious what you want to do with `sitename` in this scenario; you *might* instead mean this:

```
        name => GetCultures<List<string>>(sitename));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Looking good so far. I'll try with my actual code rather than the dummy code and let you know how I get on.

Comment: This helped me my code to compile. Thank you. I've marked Ben's answer as the one I'm accepting since it helped me achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example

```
public class TestDelegate
{
    //You don't need generic here if you always return a list of string
    public List<string> GetCulture(string s) 
    {
        return new List<string> { s };
    }

    public T GetObject<T>(string key, Func<string, T> fn)
    {
        T foundItems = fn(key);
        return foundItems;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        List<string> test = GetObject("abc", x => GetCulture(x));
    }
}
```

If you look at the method Test() and GetObject(), you can note 3 interesting things :

1. You don't have to specify the generic type on GetObject() because the compiler infer it from GetCulture()
2. The x parameter serves as an input to your delegate function, that way the method
   GetObject can use the "key" and pass it to the delegate function.
3. I replace your delegate function by "Func" with a string input and a List output.